# How to split values in a list by string and not by characters?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have read in a text file and split the rows up into two separate lists.
I'm trying to convert each of these two lists into a csv but I am running into a bit of a problem.

My current python code (using python 3) to do the writing to csv looks like this:

```
with open(bad_csv_file, 'w') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile)
      for item in bad_csv:
        wr.writerow(item)
      myfile.close()
```

The rows I'm trying to write to csv look like this:

```
0000002 1 1E-10 1851 7 5 12 1851               
0000002 0 -97.6 22.2 -9999 -9999 0 0 97687 101325 45728 41.2 1e+05 1 0 0 0 0 0 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999
0000003 1 1E-10 1851 7 10 12 1851               
0000003 0 -60 12 -9999 -9999 0 0 99993 101325 55402 25.7 1e+05 1 0 0 0 0 0 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999
0000004 50 1E-10 1851 8 16 0 1851
```

My current output looks like:

```
2,0,1,0,1,0,0,2, ,1,5,8, ,1, ,1,5,8, ,1,4,1,6, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, , , ,"
"
0,0,0,0,0,0,1, ,1,4, ,1,E,-,1,0, ,1,8,5,1, ,6, ,2,5, ,0, ,1,8,5,1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,"
"
0,0,0,0,0,0,2, ,1, ,1,E,-,1,0, ,1,8,5,1, ,7, ,5, ,1,2, ,1,8,5,1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,"
"
0,0,0,0,0,0,2, ,0, ,-,9,7,.,6, ,2,2,.,2, ,-,9,9,9,9, ,-,9,9,9,9, ,0, ,0, ,9,7,6,8,7, ,1,0,1,3,2,5, ,4,5,7,2,8, ,4,1,.,2, ,1,e,+,0,5, ,1, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,0, ,-,9,9,9,9, ,-,9,9,9,9, ,-,9,9,9,9, ,-,9,9,9,9,"
"
0,0,0,0,0,0,3, ,1, ,1,E,-,1,0, ,1,8,5,1, ,7, ,1,0, ,1,2, ,1,8,5,1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,"
```

It seems to be splitting by character as opposed to the entire string of the number. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in your code you iterate over `bad_csv` which is unbound as far as the reader knows. The naming could be somewhat more clear to make us understand what you mean to do.

Secondly, if you iterate over a `string` it'll do it `char` by `char`.
A `row` in the `csvwriter` is a sequence of [strings or numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects). It'll iterate over that. What you need to do is to split your `string` on `spaces`. `row = line.split(' ')`
Then `row` will be a sequence of your values.
If you want to remove the spaces in the end use `row = line.rstrip().split(' ')`

Oh and you don't need to close a file if you opened it with `with`.

Comment: That's done the trick for the most part, any idea why I'm getting a pair of quotation marks at the end of the line when it has been converted to a csv? i.e. 0000001,0,-94.8,28,-2.73,0,0,0,97396,101325,46887,41.2,125936,1.92,0,0,0,0,0,-9999,-9999,-9999,"-9999
"

Comment: yes, because there is a `space` there it's seen as a `string` and not as `numbers`. Strings might contain the CSV delimiter (`,`  or `;`) so it adds quotation marks.
The solution could be removing those trailing spaces first before you split. Look into `str.rstrip()`.